# Why is this the output for my linear model and how can I fix it?

Tags: r

I am trying to setup a multivariable linear programming model using R but the model keeps creating new variables in the output.

Essentially I am trying to find correlations between air quality and different factors such as population, time of day, weather readings, and a few others. For this example, I am looking at multiple different sensor locations over a months time. I have data on the actual AQI, weather data, and assumed the population in the area surrounding the sensor doesn't change over time (which might be my problem). Therefore, the population varies between the different sensor, however remains constant over the months. I then combined each sensors data into a data frame to conduct the linear programming. The code for my model is below:

```
model = lm(AQI ~ Time.of.Day + Temp + Humidity + Pressure + pop + ind + rd_dist, data = Krakdata)
```

The output is given in the picture below. I do not know why it doesn't come up with just population as an output. Instead, it outputs each population reading as another factor. Thanks!

Linear Model Output:

[image: plot]

Krakdata example. Note how the population will not change until the next sensor comes up:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: `pop` is a factor type variable, If you want `pop` as a numeric then you can change it  using `Krakdata$pop <- as.numeric(as.character(Krakdata$pop))`, but you should ask yourself first how you would like to model `pop` as a numeric or a factor. Also try to build a more robust formula call using `eval` and `bquote`.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop` is a categorical variable. You need to convert it to an integer, otherwise each value will be treated as a separated category and therefore separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

`pop` is a categorical variable, hence R treats it as such. R turns the `pop` variable into dummy variable, therefore the output. You have to convert it to numeric if this variable is supposed to be numeric in nature/in your analysis.
As to how to convert it:

```
Krakdata$pop <- as.numeric(as.character(Krakdata$pop))
```

As to how `pop` is read as factors while it resembles numbers, you need to look into your previous code or to the data itself.